# Pulling performance metrics from the confusion matrix formed in each loop in R

Tags: r, classification, confusion-matrix

I'm new to R. I'm trying to solve a 4-class classification problem with the Samme.R algorithm. Due to the scotastic nature of the algorithm, I run it 100 times with the for loop. But I don't know how to keep the performance criteria such as F1, sensitivity, sensitivity that occur in each cycle. Can you help me? Thank you from now. I tried something like the code below but couldn't.

```
f3<-c()
for (i in 1:10) {

  Sr_model1 <- booster(x_train = train[,1:3],
                      y_train = train$P,
                      classifier = "rpart",
                      method = "real",
                      x_test = test[,1:3],
                      y_test = test[,4],
                      weighted_bootstrap = FALSE,
                      max_iter = 30,
                      lambda = 0.7)
  Sr_p1 <- predict(object = Sr_model1, newdata = test, type = "pred")

  cm<-confusionMatrix(Sr_p1,test$P,mode = "everything")
  for (j in 1:ncol(cm)) {
  f3_s <- 2*cm[j,j]/(cm[j,j]+cm[j,-j]+cm[-j,j])
  f3<-c(f3,f3_s)
  }
 }
```